# Как вывести строку к которой применен метод toString

Tags: строки, java

Есть код:

```
String s = "мама папа бабушка";
String [] mas = s.split(" ");
String s2=mas.toString();
```

Как вывести строку s2, знаю есть вариант использовать `Arrays.toString[mas]`, но он не подходит.

**Update**
В общем случае задача выглядит следующим образом: -есть строка `String` со значениями; -далее я разбиваю эту строку пробелом, или другими символами; -далее выполняю какие-то перестановки, и в результате массив элементов, который мне нужен, нужно привести к первоначальному виду. Использую метод `toString()` чтобы привести массив `String` к `String`. Но когда использую нужно положить новую строку например в файл то записывает не значения строки, а `String.Java.lang 436w46543`. Каким образом вывести значения строки полученной при использовании метода `toString()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String str = "мама папа бабушка";
    String[] words = str.split(" ");

    String temp = words[1];
    words[1] = words[0];
    words[0] = temp;

    String newStr = concatArray(words);

    System.out.println(newStr);

    try (BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("file.txt"))) {
        writer.write(newStr);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public static String concatArray(String[] words) {
    StringBuilder rez = new StringBuilder();

    for (String word : words) {
        rez.append(word).append(" ");
    }

    return rez.toString();
}
```

Можно еще так, правда появятся запятые:

```
String newStr = Arrays.toString(words);
newStr = newStr.substring(1, newStr.length() - 1);
```

При желании можно в этой строке удалить запятые replaceAll'ом, правда тогда удалятся все запятые, даже те, которые были в словах

Answer (score 1):

Можете попробовать так:

```
String s2 = StringUtils.join(mas," ");
```

Второй параметр - разделитель. Как я понял, вам нужно оставить пробел.

Answer (score 0):

Может, в цикле?

```
for (String str : mas){
   System.out.println(str);
}
```

или что вам точнее нужно

Comment: println можно без пробела

Comment: Нужно вывести имено переменную s2.

Comment: Вывести получится либо методом Arrays.toString(mas), либо циклом.

Answer (score 0):

Зачем `s2`?

```
for( str in mas ) {
    System.out.println( str );
}
```

Результат метода `split` - коллекция строк. И нужно с коллекцией работать соответствующими средствами.

Comment: Да, при применении метода toString к массиву String, все значения, которые входили в массив становятся одной строкой? если да каким образом ее вывести?

Comment: @JAVAvladuxa, 
А зачем вы сначала пытаетесь разбить строку на токены, а потом выводить ЭТУ же строку?

Comment: После разбиения провожу некоторые действия по сортировке. В результате получаю нужный массив элементов, и к нему применяю метод toString.

Comment: @JAVAvladuxa, не применяйте toString, так как этот метод не перегружен для массивов. Либо Arrays.sort(...), либо цыкл. Если Java 8, то можно еще люмбды использовать, но не думаю, что оно вам сейчас надо